# Angular2+, will Event emitter trigger change detection?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

- parent component has one child component(child1)
- child1 component has an input property person and OnPush
  changeDetection strategy
- inside of child component, use settimeout in ngOnInit to mutable change person.

  - normally dom view will not update because of the onPush strategy
  - however if I use event emitter to emit this mutable change to its
    parent which in turn change the property binding(mutable), the view
    gets update.

So my question is here, will event emitter trigger view check?(change detection).
Thanks!

parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<app-child1 [person]="person", (changOnPerson)="onPersonChange($event)">',
})
export class AppComponent {
  person: Person = {
    name: 'Alex',
    age: 20
 };
 constructor() {
 }
 onPersonChange($event) {
    this.person = $event.change;
  }
}
```

child1.compnent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child1',
  template: '{{person | json}}',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class Child1Component implements onInit {
  @Input() person: Person;
  @Output() changOnPerson = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.person.name += ' ,abc';

      // core code here !
      this.changOnPerson.emit({ change: this.person });
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will as EventEmitter is an Observable, thus I don't think it is wrapped in NgZone.

Although don't rely on Change Detection defaults if possible. Just use OnPush.

Answer (score 0):

### Mostly from observations, in Angular 15

- After the function passed to `setTimeout()` is run, there is a change detection cycle at the top of the tree (a 'tick', I guess). **This is still true when using `OnPush`**. However, in this situation, this does not necessarily mean change detection will reach the view of the component which `setTimeout()` was called from.
- When an `EventEmitter` has a handler/listener registered, calling `emit` will result in the views being marked dirty up to the root (`markForCheck()`-style).
- As a result, if you emit a signal within a function whose execution is deferred via `setTimeout()`, and the parent component has registered a handler for that signal, you will have a change detection cycle for your component after the function is run.

### Remarks about investigating change detection

- When you inject NgZone in your component, you can wrap the call to `setTimeout()` in a function passed to `this.zone.runOutsideAngular()` to bypass the change detection cycle.
- If you want to know if/when change detection runs for a component that has a child component, you can monitor the execution of `ngDoCheck()` on that child component. It is run for each change detection cycle of the (parent) component.